# Activity created twice

Tags: android, screen-orientation, activity-lifecycle

I have set locked orientation

[image]

and added the sample code with 2 simple classes like below:

`SplashLandscapeActivity.java`

```
public class SplashLandscapeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("start", "xxxx start Activity SplashLandscapeActivity");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashLandscapeActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("start", "xxxx onDestroy Activity SplashLandscapeActivity");
    }
}
```

`TestActivity.java`

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("start", "xxxx start Activity TestActivity "
                + getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("start", "xxxx onDestroy Activity TestActivity "
                + getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashLandscapeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I use `new Handler().postDelayed` (`SplashLandscapeActivity.java`) to start `TestActivity`, It's started twice, the first one has `Landscape` orientation then switch back to `portrait`. The log showed it all:

> xxxx start Activity SplashLandscapeActivity
>
> xxxx start Activity TestActivity 2 // <== landscape
>
> xxxx onDestroy Activity TestActivity 1
>
> xxxx start Activity TestActivity 1 // <== portrait
>
> xxxx onDestroy Activity SplashLandscapeActivity

And if I remove that `Handler`, `TestActivity` now started with portrait like normal.

> xxxx start Activity SplashLandscapeActivity
>
> xxxx start Activity TestActivity 1
>
> xxxx onDestroy Activity SplashLandscapeActivity

So, my question is:

1- Is this system issue or its intended behavior? Why `activity` is restarted even the `screenOrientation` was set fixed in `Manifest`?

2- Actually, my real project do not have any `Handler` but has the same issue that `activity` started twice (after start with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`). How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your Manifest orientation. Like keeping both in portrait mode

Comment: What do you mean? I use them to simulate my issue. Anyway, my expected is this `activity` never started twice.

Comment: If the handler was removed and you've launched the app while your device is in locked portrait , does the app rotates like momentarily before reaching ```TestActivity```? or does it  directly jump to ```TestActivity``` in portrait without rotating?

My guess is this could be due to the config changes being called after the activity has ```onCreate``` and probably ```onResume``` executed, and if no config changes happened like when skipping the ```SplashLandscapeActivity``` and directly starting ```TestActivity``` it wouldn't be called hence it wouldn't restart ```TestActivity```.

Comment: @ahasbini `onConfigurationChanged` is never called on `TestActivity`, even if it was restarted by system (I guessed).

Comment: I can give one tip, You can check `onSaveInstanceState` from `onCreate` method, second recreation of activity will have something different than null.

Comment: @deadfish, It's the basic knowledge and I hope the fix was easy like what you talked, but it wasn't . Also, can you answer me `why activity is restarted even the screenOrientation was set fixed in Manifest`?

Comment: you shouldn't worry about why android creates and destroys these activities on rotation, your activity should gracefully handle recreation.

Comment: @gjsalot Ofcause my `activity` is rotation successful, but my UI and logic code are failed because `activity` was initialized twice (`onCreate, onResume`)

Comment: @NamNH you'll need to fix your "UI and logic code" then.

Answer (score 4):

In your manifest file edit the TestActivity block like this

`<activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 comments to prevent TestActivity start twice. Hope Help you

1. use `sensorPortrait` instead of `portrait`in the TestActivity. And the TestActivity will not start twice, but it will rotate it to match the way in which the device is held by the user.
2. add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`  to the TestAcitivty in your Manifest.xml.It will call `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` instead of restart.

I have not found this issue in Android N.

Comment: How about if UI is different between `Land` and `Port`, Is `setContentView` in `onConfigurationChanged` recommended? Also, can you answer me `why activity is restarted even the screenOrientation was set  fixed in Manifest?`

Comment: I have not found any official document to talk about why activity restart when the screenOrientation is not same as the starter. BUT it seem that android start activity with portrait because of starter is portrait, and ignore the current landscape state. The reason seems to be to predict the state you are using。So you have to handle this problem at runtime.[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html?hl=en-es)

Comment: Not sure about `starter` or any relation, because without `handler`, `activity` is started exactly same `manifest` config. Anyway, thanks for your time, the main idea of this question is not about `How to fix...`, it's about `why...`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the flag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your TestActivity in manifest file to look like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".TestActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
/>
```

This should solve your problem.

Reason, why config changes is required is:
Now regarding why configChanges is required is, from android docs:

> If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific
>   configuration change and you have a performance limitation that
>   requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that
>   your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents
>   the system from restarting your activity.

Visit [android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: Your answered does not resolve my question. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104109/activity-created-twice#comments-44213942)

Comment: Have you tried. I got the following logs with the changes I suggested:
D/start: xxxx start Activity TestActivity 1
D/start: xxxx onDestroy Activity SplashLandscapeActivity

Comment: Like my other comments, your answer is not focused on my question. Why do I need to set  `configChanges` option while I already set fixed `screenOrientation`?

Comment: But does it solves the issue? That's first concern. See my updated answer.

Comment: No, it's not easy to fix my real project with your simple code, it causes many side effects. I want to ask my question here to find out the root cause of my issue that `Why do I need to set configChanges option while I already set fixed screenOrientation?`.

Comment: As per your sample code, there are two activities, one in landscape and other in portrait. Android will honor the orientations as per the manifest declaration. Switching from one orientation to another will recreate your activities, unless you want to handle the configuration change by yourself. For more info on this, visit the android doc link specified in my updated answer. Hope that helps!
And what side effects are you talking about? May be you need to re visit the way you have written you project?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `manifest.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashLandscapeActivity"
                android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".TestActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I don't like the `configChanges` options, also your answer is not focused on my question.

Comment: if you don't want configChanges then you should use this
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:taskAffinity="">

for more details : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Answer (score 0):

Can change MainActicity to

```
public class SplashLandscapeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static boolean isRunStop = false;
    static int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            counter++;
            Log.d("start", "xxxx run handler SplashLandscapeActivity. Time : "+counter);
            Toast.makeText(SplashLandscapeActivity.this, ""+counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("start", "xxxx run handler SplashLandscapeActivity");
                if(!isRunStop )
                {
                      startActivity(new Intent(SplashLandscapeActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
                      isRunStop =true;
                      finish();
                }

            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("start", "xxxx onDestroy Activity SplashLandscapeActivity");
    }
}
```

Handler is called in another thread that does not go away when you change your screen orientation previous handler gone and runs. You can have more time to test handler several times to change the screen orientation.

Comment: Your answer is not focused on my question. Also, as I said the `startActivity`  called only 1 time, but the `TestActivity` started twice.

Comment: Log `Log.d("start", "xxxx run handler SplashLandscapeActivity");` this code run twice.

Comment: Which your emulator version? On all my emulators, Handler just runs only 1 time.

Comment: My emulator version is 23. For test, change increase time from 500 to 5000 and change quickly screen orientation .

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I don't want you try to make new cases.